# Open modal and scroll to a specific DIV

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a link that opens a modal window.
I would like to open the modal window and scroll to a specific DIV inside it.

HTML:

```
<a href="#teamMembers" data-toggle="modal" class="teamMemebrScroll1">read more</a>
<a href="#teamMembers" data-toggle="modal" class="teamMemebrScroll2">read more</a>
<a href="#teamMembers" data-toggle="modal" class="teamMemebrScroll3">read more</a>

<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="teamMembers" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="container" data-id="teamMemebrScroll1">....</div>
      <div class="container" data-id="teamMemebrScroll2">....</div>
      <div class="container" data-id="teamMemebrScroll3">....</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// scroll to team member 2
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(".teamMemebrScroll2").click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top }, 1000);
  });
});
```

The modal opened correctly, but it always scrolling to the top.

Answer (score 2):

1. In your approach, you are targeting the `$('html,body')` but you want to scroll to content inside modal when modal open so it should be `$('modalselector')`
2. You are trying to create multiple `click` events which you don't need and can achieve the same result by using [BS modal event function](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) by adding addtional `data attributes` in modal trigger button.

Made some changes in Modal trigger button, added data attribute `data-id` and no need the `click` event as you are trying.

```
<a href="#teamMembers" data-toggle="modal" data-id="teamMemebrScroll1" class="teamMemebrScroll1">read more</a>
<a href="#teamMembers" data-toggle="modal" data-id="teamMemebrScroll2" class="teamMemebrScroll2">read more</a>
<a href="#teamMembers" data-toggle="modal" data-id="teamMemebrScroll3" class="teamMemebrScroll3">read more</a>
```

and BS modal event function

```
$('#teamMembers').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    //alert('modal shown');
    var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id'); // <--fetch modal button data-id when modal shown
});
```

As you already added data attributes `data-id` to elements inside modal

```
  <div class="container" data-id="teamMemebrScroll1">....</div>
  <div class="container" data-id="teamMemebrScroll2">....</div>
  <div class="container" data-id="teamMemebrScroll3">....</div>
```

So just need to match the modal button `data-id` with element `data-id` inside the modal and scroll to it when modal open

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#teamMembers').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id'); // Modal button data-id
        var team = $('.container[data-id="' + id + '"]'); // Element data-id with match the Modal button data-id
        $(this).animate({ // Modal
            scrollTop: team.offset().top // Scroll to the element
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu54q9jr/)

---

If you want to have more control over scrolling using same above approach, way back I found a very small script and it does a little better job. Check the following

[Fiddle with Scroll Top plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu54q9jr/1/)

Comment: Thank you, almost there. When writing your code I get an exception: `'e' is undefined` in the second line of `$(document).ready`. Also, I'm not using the `<div class="modal-dialog">` inside the modal. It seems to distort the UI, but without it - the scrolling does not happens.

Comment: Code in answer updated, Don't know how but I missed a line in code

Comment: Online from mobile, will add the solution without 'modal-dialog' soon, event will not fire without 'modal-dialog' selector

Comment: one option is to remove `class="fade"` from modal if you don't wana use `<div class="modal-dialog">`

Comment: btw what version of BS you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try to when you open the window, the first thing you do is going to a link.
This link goes to the specific div "teamMembers"

```
<a href="#TeamMembers" ... />
```

Use Php on your window like this:

```
<?php
   header('Location: #TeamMembers');
?>
```

Comment: I've updated the code above. I would liker the modal window `teamMembers` to open and then scroll to `teamMember2`.